# what is the most straightforward way of writing the content of a variable to page?

Tags: javascript

I have a `<p></p>` and I want to put a text inside it a text that a JS variable holds,
is it possible to put a `<script>` inside the `<p>` and just write it there, without using any kind of DOM searching (not even innerHTML)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p>
<script>
var theVariable="this has some content";
document.write(theVariable);
</script>
</p>
```

hope that helps and is what you wanted.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SbK4B/)

Comment: thanx, but isn't document.write refreshes the page and writes to it inly it's content?

Comment: Only if you run it after the document has been turned into a DOM, at which point you have to use DOM manipulation.